# Handling WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP inside WM_COMMAND win32 GUI C++

Tags: c++, win32gui

I am creating a window with a dropdown list like this:

[image: DropDown List]

If I click on any of the first four options, including their sub-options, then I want to handle that option. The problem is I need to use `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONUP` and some other stuff like them in these options and don't know how.

I don't know what to do inside `case WM_COMMAND` to handle all these options, so here is my `WindowProcedure`:

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        case WM_CREATE:
            AddMenu(hwnd);
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:

            switch(wParam)
            {
                case Line_DDA:
                    break;
                case Line_Midpoint:
                    break;
                case Line_Parametric:
                    break;

                case Ellipse_Direct:
                    break;
                case Ellipse_Polar:
                    break;
                case Ellipse_Midpoint:
                    break;

                case Line_Clipping:
                    break;

                case Convex_Filling:
                    break;

                case Load_File:
                    break;

                case Save_File:
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is `AddMenu()`:

```c
void AddMenu(HWND hwnd)
{
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hSubMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hLineMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hEllipseMenu = CreateMenu();

    AppendMenu(hLineMenu, MF_STRING, Line_DDA, "DDA");
    AppendMenu(hLineMenu, MF_STRING, Line_Midpoint, "Midpoint");
    AppendMenu(hLineMenu, MF_STRING, Line_Parametric, "Parametric");

    AppendMenu(hEllipseMenu, MF_STRING, Ellipse_Direct, "Direct");
    AppendMenu(hEllipseMenu, MF_STRING, Ellipse_Polar, "Polar");
    AppendMenu(hEllipseMenu, MF_STRING, Ellipse_Midpoint, "Midpoint");

    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hLineMenu, "Line");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hEllipseMenu, "Ellipse");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, Line_Clipping, "Line Clipping");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, Convex_Filling, "Convex Filling");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, Load_File, "Load");
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, Save_File, "Save");

    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP,(UINT_PTR)hSubMenu , "Draw");

    SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by needing "to use WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP and some other stuff like them in these options"? 
Do you mean that when a menu item fires you want to perform different behavior based on the state of the mouse button?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to draw a line, ellipse ..etc and to do so I need to take its coordinates (x,y) which can be taken by ```WM_LBUTTONDOWN``` and ```WM_LBUTTONUP```

Comment: oh so you want to know about how to implement the entire interaction in which the user sweeps out, for example, an ellipse via dragging the mouse?

Comment: You don't use `WM_LBUTTON...` messages with menus themselves, only with windows.  `WM_COMMAND` will tell you which menu item was selected by the user. Remember that choice in a variable somewhere. THEN, when you do get `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` at a later time, remember those mouse coordinates in another variable, THEN when you get `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, you can draw between the two sets of coordinates as needed, based on the value of the first variable you saved, THEN stop drawing when you get `WM_LBUTTONUP`.

Answer (score 1):

Remy Lebeau's comment points in the right direction.  Let's make it more concrete.

In event-driven programming, you often need to know what's happened in the past in order to decide what to do now.  When an event happens, you need to know what the event is (e.g., a WM_LBUTTONDOWN) *and* the current state.

For your program, we need to keep track of a few different things, so let's bundle them up into a struct.

```
struct State {
  enum { Idle, WaitingForPoint0, WaitingForPoint1, DrawIt } action;
  DrawType type;  // e.g., Line_DDA, Line_Midpoint, Ellipse_Direct, etc.
  POINT points[2];
};
```

You need some way to associate an instance of this `State` with each instance of your window.  For now, we'll just make it a global variable and assume you have only window of this type in your program.

```
State g_state = {Idle};
```

When the user selects one of the drawing options from the menu, you update the current state.  For example:

```
case Line_DDA:
    g_state.action = WaitingForPoint0;
    g_state.type = LineDDA;
    break;

case Line_Midpoint:
    g_state.action = WaitingForPoint0;
    g_state.type = Line_Midpoint;
    break;

// and so on
```

When the user presses the button, we have to check the current state to know what to do.

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    switch (g_state.action) {
        case Idle:  // just ignore the click
            break;
        case WaitingForPoint0:
            g_state.points[0].x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            g_state.points[0].y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
            g_state.action = WaitingForPoint2;
            break;
        case WaitingForPoint1:
            g_state.points[1].x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            g_state.points[1].y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
            g_state.action = DrawIt;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
```

Finally, when the window needs to be updated, we check the state it figure out what shape show be there.

```
case WM_PAINT:
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    if (g_state.action == DrawIt) {
      switch (g_state.type) {
          case Line_DDA:
              YourDrawLineDDA(hdc, g_state.points[0], g_state.points[1]);
              break;
          case Line_Midpoint:
              YourDrawLineMidpoint(hdc, g_state.points[0], g_state.points[1]);
              break;
          // and so on
      }
    }
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
```

This can get pretty verbose, but it illustrates the essentials of what you want to do.  You can certainly factor this type of code to be more concise, elegant, and extensible.